# How can i append the first element of an array to itself inside a SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add the first entry of a locally created array to its own end.

The string_to_array inside the SELECT creates an array of the data extrated from an xml source via xpath.

I would like to duplicate the first entry of this array and paste it at its own end, inside the body of this query.

```sql
SELECT
    xxxd AS id,
    string_to_array( 
        regexp_replace(
            (xpath('//ns:L/text()', donnee::xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['ns', 'z:e:r:t:y']]))::varchar, '[{}]', '', 'gi')::text , ',') 
    AS lat
    ,
INTO test_table FROM source_table
```

I'am trying things with `array_append(anyarray, anyelement)` but can't really get something working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on giorgiga idea, you can create a function which updates the array the way you need and then wrap your extracted array with that function.  For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION arr_extend(arr anyarray) RETURNS anyarray
    AS $$ SELECT array_append(arr, arr[1]) $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT arr_extend(array['a','b','c']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll most probably need a subquery and `array_append` - eg:

```
with subquery as (
  select array['a','b','c'] as arr
)
select array_append(arr, arr[1])
  from subquery
```

results in `a,b,c,a`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will try something like this right now, but in my real case ( and not the simplified one i described in my original post ) I can have a lot of parrallel arrays in my SELECT that would need this operation. I'am not shure your way would scale well to this constraint.